# How to backup Ubuntu settings for future use in case of Ubuntu Reinstall?

Tags: backup, settings

I have recently installed **Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS** and customized settings, installed some apps, etc for my personal use. These include CopyQ for the clipboard, VSCode for code editing, and also a number of customized shortcuts and settings for Ubuntu. It definitely took me some time to make these changes. However, I don't want to do this thing again in future to avoid time wastage.

- As Ubuntu is having Ubuntu One account, is there any way that I can
  back up my settings in that account for future reinstallations of
  Ubuntu?
- If I install Ubuntu on some other machine, is there any way
  that I can move these settings to that machine using an Ubuntu one
  account or some kind of file transfer?
- Even if Ubuntu One account is not for this purpose, are there some
  other methods to do so?

> This is pretty similar to Google Chrome where if sync is enabled, our
> data is moved to the new browser when we log in to our old Google
> Account.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore the application settings, you could first install the applications on a fresh Ubuntu install.
You could back up/restore your dotfiles, which store settings for your applications.
An application such as [chezmoi](https://www.chezmoi.io/), for example.
You could also back up and restore your home `(~)` folder.